# Hibernate @Synchronize does not seem to be working

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have 2 Entitites, one maps to a database table, the other to a database view.
The data of the view depends on the table.

```
@javax.persistence.Table(name = "BOOKING_INFO", schema = "BOOKING")
@Entity
public class BookingInfo extends AbstractBooking {


@javax.persistence.Table(name = "BOOKING_VIEW", schema = "BOOKING")
@Entity
@Immutable
public class BookingView extends AbstractBooking {
```

This works fine in most cases, however when we write (insert or update) the Booking entity and then do queries (in my case a count) on the BookingView entity, we get stale data.

Why this happens is clear to me (hibernate caching, it only flushes when it detects that a select needs some data flushed).
So if I would do a query on the Booking entity, it would trigger a flush.

I have found the `@Synchronize` Annotation in Hibernate which sounds like it should fix this problem, like this:

```
@javax.persistence.Table(name = "BOOKING_VIEW", schema = "BOOKING")
@Entity
@Immutable
@Synchronize("BOOKING.BOOKING_INFO")
public class BookingView extends AbstractBooking {
```

However this does not make any difference (flush only happens at the end of the transaction). Also the documentation I have found about this annotation is quite lacking and not very helpful.

EDIT: I also tried `@Synchronize("BOOKING_INFO")` (without the schema name, and also lowercase, but that made no difference)

The docs say that it is mostly used with `@Subselect` but it is not a must (I don't want that).

Has anyone ever successfully used this annotation?
Is there any other way to handle database views in Hibernate?
Am I missing something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to a colleague we were able to debug and fix this, the problem was that our Hibernate naming-strategy lowercased our table-names, so the correct annotaiton is:

```
@Synchronize("BOOKING.booking_info")
```

How to debug this:

set breakpoints in Hibernates `ActionQueue` class in the `areTablesToBeUpdated` methods.

There we saw that it compared "BOOKING.BOOKING_VIEW" to "BOOKING.booking_view".

We think this is a bug in hibernate because it should either apply the naming-strategies also to the values from @Synchronize or compare these case-insensitive (which could theoretically lead to too many flushes if you have a crazy database which uses tables with the same name only differentiated by casing).

Created a Hibernate issue: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10002